# Как спарсить информацию со всех страниц сайта

Tags: python, парсер

Подскажите пожалуйста, как спарсить информацию со всех страниц сайта, если нет определенного количества страниц, а есть только кнопка "следующая страница" и "предыдущая". Python

```html
<p class="text-center">
    
  <a href="/?appid=730&amp;page=1"><span class="fa fa-backward"></span></a>

  <a href="/?appid=730&amp;page=110"><span class="fa fa-step-backward"></span></a>

  <strong>Page: 111</strong>

  <a href="/?appid=730&amp;page=112"><span class="fa fa-step-forward"></span></a>
</p>
```

Comment: найти закономерность, как обычно... снова bitskins.com? если так, то их там - 51   ;)

Comment: В зависимости от того, какая это кнопка... Пожалуйста, приведите её HTML-код, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: ахахахаха, очень пробленый сайт для меня), а вообще там больше 51 страницы 
https://prnt.sc/zdph7x

Comment: <p class="text-center">
  <a href="/?appid=730&amp;page=1"><span class="fa fa-backward"></span></a>
  <a href="/?appid=730&amp;page=110"><span class="fa fa-step-backward"></span></a>
  <strong>Page: 111</strong>
  <a href="/?appid=730&amp;page=112"><span class="fa fa-step-forward"></span></a>
</p>
Я попытался оставить код, но не получилось, только как коментарий

Comment: @OlejaInteger странно, у меня после 51-й - ничего... может, из-за авторизации? ну, ок, перебирайте номер в ulr-е, пока не перестанут появляться div class="panel item-featured panel-default" ps кстати, если предідущий ответ помог, можно отметить его как принятый галочкой под его голосование

Comment: Плохо, когда в шапку сайта вставлен календарь, и там есть ссылки на предыдущие даты. Так сделано во многих блого-ориентированных движках. Робот, который ходит по ссылкам, быстро добирается до даты куликовской битвы и уносится еще дальше, вглубь веков...

Comment: @OlejaInteger https://bitskins.com/api/python#totp_code

Comment: Огромное спасибо